# VBA to Call Label from Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, label, goto

Simply I need to know if I can call specific label located in another sheet on the same workbook.

I know I can call label In the same sheet easily but what about label from another sheet ??

Or is there another similar way to do that

For Example:
usually when we are running a code we can call another module code by calling its subroutine name like, Label is a way to skip lines and start from specific lines

```
Dim AnswerP As String
    AnswerP = Application.InputBox("Do You Have a file to be uploaded! Please type yes ", Default:="yes", Title:="Checking File Existance!")
    'If Answer is Yes Upload file and Goto Another File (Mobile label)
    If AnswerP = "yes" Then    
    Z_Import_Package_2        'Calling another module code by its name
    Dim UploadedP As String
    UploadedP = "Selected"
    GoTo Mobile  'Label
    ElseIf AnswerP = "no" Then     'Checking Next Mobile File
    UploadedP = "Skipped"

Dim LastRowCP As Long
LastRowCP = Ssheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
Ssheet4.Range("C3:C" & LastRowCP).Copy Destination:=DestShtBPS.Cells(LR_DestShtB, "C")

MobileF:
    Dim AnswerM As String
    AnswerM = Application.InputBox("Do You Have another File to be uploaded! Please type yes ", Default:="yes", Title:="Checking File Existance!")
    If AnswerM = "yes" Then    
    Z_Import_Mobile_2                     'Calling another module code by its name
```

so can i call MobileF Label for example directly from another sheet
as calling subroutine label will call the full code from its start which is not diresed

Comment: "I know I can call label In the same sheet easily"- would help to post your code for that, as it's not obvious what you mean by "calling" a label.

Comment: @TimWilliams Question is edited with an example as you required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Goto` is not really a good approach for flow-control: we have plenty of better alternatives. About the only need for `Goto` outside of error handling is to break out of multiple nested loops. Suggest you restructure your code to use regular flow control (if/then) and break out any code you need to call from multiple places into standalone methods (Sub or Function)

```vb
If MsgBox("Do You Have a file to be uploaded?", _
          vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Checking File") = vbYes Then
    Z_Import_Package_2        'Calling another module code by its name
    Dim UploadedP As String
    UploadedP = "Selected"
    MobileF  'call MobileF
Else
    UploadedP = "Skipped"
    Dim LastRowCP As Long
    LastRowCP = Ssheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    Ssheet4.Range("C3:C" & LastRowCP).Copy Destination:=DestShtBPS.Cells(LR_DestShtB, "C")
    '...
    '...
```

Move MobileF to standalone Sub:

```vb
Sub MobileF()
    If MsgBox("Do You Have another File to be uploaded?", _
              vbQuestion + vbYesNo, _
              "Checking File Existance!") = vbYes Then
        Z_Import_Mobile_2
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you it realled helped me and solved another issue which i did not ask about too. really i forgot about vbQuestion + vbYesNo.

this code is working fine but i have another issue happened which is related to connect this code to another one and i will ask about in separate question now.

Once again Thank you.